# Add CSS rules with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, jsp

I don't know how to use CSS. So I am asking here.
I am creating a JSP page. I have added two tables in my JSP page using Twitter Bootstrap. I need to add different alignment for both tables. Since I am using bootsrap both tables having same alignment.

This is my code

```
<div>
<table class="table table-bordered source">
//table 1 contents
</table>
</div>

<div>
<table class="table table-hover target">
//table 2 contents
</table>
</div>
```

I want to align the text to center for table 1 and left for table 2. Table 2 header should be alinged to center and table 2 boreder should be blue.

So I tried this CSS

```
    .table.table-hover.target td {
        text-align: left !important;
    }

    .table.table-hover.target th {
        text-align: right !important;
    }

    .table.table-bordered.source td
    {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    .table.target
    {
            border-color:blue;
    }
```

It is not working.
When I give

```
.table td
{
    text-align:left !important;
}
```

it aligns both table contents to left.
I dont now CSS. How can I write the CSS rule?

Comment: Why are you adding the text-align style to `.table td`?  What's wrong with the first CSS rules you gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably have something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Your page</title>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    ...

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

right below the `bootstrap-responsive.css` (or if you are not using responsive layout, you will not even use this file, witch would then be below the `bootstrap.css` call).

add a new file like:

```
<link href="/assets/css/application.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and add all your override rules to that file, the code above will look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Your page</title>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/css/application.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    ...

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the line `"/assets/css/application.css"` will say that your code will be in that specific path, change it for your needs

**Comments:**

Remember to comment your CSS rules so others (and even you in 6 month time for example) will understand why did you wrote that... in CSS you can add comments wrap it with `/* ... */`

for example:

```
/* TABLES OVERRIDE: so they look like the main theme */
.table td
{
    text-align:left !important;
}
```